# Why is my website certificate not verified by all browsers. Is this related to my CA or just misconfiguration?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl

I have a certificate signed by https://www.noip.com which I'm using in my website (https://angola.sytes.net), but the certificate is only recognized by some browsers in some places.

If you take a look at my website you'll see that the certificate was issued by `TrustCor DV SSL CA - G2`.

Is that related to the certificate signer?

Comment: **It's not the CA, it's the chain certs**. Although you can use another CA if you like, TrustCor _is_ widely trusted. Your problem is that validating any public SSL/TLS cert needs at least one chain cert (in this case two) which the server is required to send, but your server doesn't. _Some_ clients, especially browsers, can find the chain cert(s) on their own, but they aren't required to, and those that don't reject your cert. See https://whatsmychaincert.com/?angola.sytes.net . If you switch to LE but don't use _its_ chain cert(s) you'll have the same problem.

Comment: It’s getting clear. I’ll take a look at the link and also on how to add the whole chain. Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: You can do these check yourself to determine the issue.
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=angola.sytes.net

Comment: Thank you all for your insights. by replacing the certificate file for a file containing all the certificate chain, the issue was solved. You can see now that my website certificate is recognized by any browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from Dave Thompson's answer, thanks a lot for that!

I just had to go to [www.whatsmychaincert.com/?angola.sytes.net](http://www.whatsmychaincert.com/?angola.sytes.net), there I saw that my certificate chain was wrong. Actually I did not add the certificate chain.

The solution was to replace the certificate file by a file containing the whole chain - something like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHnTCCBoWgAwIBAgINALvtKN6lcmz0a5LenTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBbMQsw...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEtjCCA56gAwIBAgIUIkYvfVtKEOOpNHBTTXF6pfTWoj8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
GgAwIBAgIUKovf56gGbRis1wiRs49luaW2zVkwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```